# what is $var means on save($var) on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question ,

```
public function addNote(makenote $note) {
    return $this->makenote()->save($note);
}
```

why there is note var on save method ?
what does it do?

Comment: Do you know how PHP functions work? Do you see any other `$note` in your code snippet that might give you a clue? This might be helpful: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Answer (score 0):

In this case I believe $note refers to the instance of a related model that you want to save.

```
public function addNote(MakeNote $note) {
    return $this->makenote()->save($note);
}
```

I would assume that on your Model there is a method that looks something like this. This method tell Eloquent that there is a model that is related to your current model.

```
public function makenote()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\MakeNote');
}
```

If you do not pass an instance of MakeNote, the $note in this case, there will be nothing to relate to your current model, thus nothing to save.

I'd really go check out the documentation on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2) also if you want more tutorials [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com) is a great resource.

Your question is getting down-voted too, because you should include more information about your question and some more examples of your code.